# Building basic webpages with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, web

Background: I am learning ASP.NET MVC, I am a decent HTML/CSS writer with some JS but I know c# and I am looking for something more in web development.

Question: I am about to create a basic "brochure" (static) webpage, no database needed, for a friend. A contact form will be used along with some pretty JS. Is it overkill to create a new MVC project in VS and build their site using this technology (disregarding the small price increase in hosting)? I really want to begin playing with ASP and I wonder if this is a perfect starting point.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "brochure" I'm assuming that all the content will be static? If so, yes it's overkill. You aren't going to get to use many of the MVC features.

If you want to play with ASP.NET MVC, just do it. I'd recommend maybe some Pluralsight videos, or a book like ASP.NET MVC in Action (Manning) series or Professional ASP.NET MVC (Wrox) series.